# How to compare two 'wei' values?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, ethers.js

Here is the code snippet of my smart contract:

```js
provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum);
signer = await provider.getSigner();
let contract = new ethers.Contract(NFTMarketplaceAddress, Marketplace.abi, signer);
const address = await signer.getAddress();
const balance = await provider.getBalance(address);
const priceInWei = ethers.parseEther(NFTData.price.toString());
  
console.log(balance.lt(priceInWei))
```

I'm trying to check whether the `balance` is lower than the `priceInWei`.
That's why I'm using [ethers.js library's `lt` function](https://docs.ethers.org/v6/api/utils/fixed-point-math/#FixedNumber-lt).

But the console shows my the following error:

```
TypeError: balance.lt is not a function
```

How to fix this problem?

I've tried the following technique:

```
console.log(balance < priceInWei)
```

Certainly that doesn't give me the correct output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the `BrowserProvider` in your snippet, I'm assuming you're using ethers v6.

This version returns native JavaScript `BigInt` from the `provider.getBalance()` function as well as from the `parseEther()` function.

You can simply compare the `BigInt` values with the `<` sign.

```
console.log(balance < priceInWei)
```

---

The `FixedNumber` might be used e.g. for comparing token amounts where the tokens have different number of decimals.

Or possibly when a future version of Solidity implements returning [Fixed point numbers](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.21/types.html#fixed-point-numbers), these returned numbers might be encoded into the `FixedNumber` type in ethers.js.

But right now, it doesn't really seem to be a widely used feature.